# Argo-CD : trying to deploy app using app of apps pattern - warning : ExcludedResourceWarning Resource /Application test is excluded in the settings

Tags: argocd

Seems like I need to modify `argocd-cm.yaml` config map to include resource of kind "Application".
But i couldn't see any `argocd-cm configmap`. I don't have `kubectl` utility to modify the config map.

Is there a way to view modify `argocd-cm` by logging in to argo website?

App of apps pattern:
https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/cluster-bootstrapping/

To view config for the current project in argo, i navigated to settings/projects/testproject and i see below settings:

**Settings**

The cluster resource allow list is empty.

cluster resource deny list:

```
Kind   Group

 *        *
```

Namespace Resource allow list is empty

Namespace resource deny list

```
     kind                Group
     ResourceQuota
     LimitRange
     NetworkPolicy
```

Not sure if any one of these settings is not allowing the resource of  Kind: "Application"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to modify the `argocd-cm` settings via the UI.

Deploying Apps from other Apps is something which should be reserved for admins, because it allows you to deploy Apps with any `project` you choose. If you do not have access to edit `argocd-cm`, then you should not have access to deploy Apps with arbitrary `project` values.

Comment: "ExcludedResourceWarning Resource /Application test is excluded in the settings"
Is this warning saying us the resource of kind "Application" is excluded in the `argocd-cm `  configmap?

Comment: That's my understanding. https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/declarative-setup/#resource-exclusioninclusion

I don't think it's coming from a Project-level restriction.